# rbinding two columns together in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have:

```
col 1,  col2,  col3,   col4     val
 a       b       c       d       5
 f       g       h       i       6
...
```

I want to rbind two columns together. I have the following:

```
newcol1,    newcol2
  a           b
  c           d
  f           g
  h           i
 ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use vector recycling method to create two column dataframe.

```
result <- data.frame(newcol1 = unlist(df[c(TRUE, FALSE)]), 
                     newcol2 = unlist(df[c(FALSE, TRUE)]), row.names = NULL)

result

#  newcol1 newcol2
#1       a       b
#2       f       g
#3       c       d
#4       h       i
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c("a", "f"), col2 = c("b", "g"), col3 = c("c", 
"h"), col4 = c("d", "i")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to include something.

Comment: @stackovf1 You can include the columns that you want `df <- df[1:4]` and then use the above answer.

Comment: thanks, I have another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65549351/rbinding-two-data-frame-with-same-num-of-columns

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `data.table` option using `rbindlist`

```
data.table::rbindlist(split.default(df, ceiling(seq_along(df) / 2)), use.names = FALSE)
```

which gives

```
   col1 col2
1:    a    b
2:    f    g
3:    c    d
4:    h    i
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(col1 = c("a", "f"), col2 = c("b", "g"), col3 = c("c", 
"h"), col4 = c("d", "i")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-2L))
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to include something.

Answer (score 1):

Create example:

```r
dd <- as.data.frame(matrix(letters[1:8], byrow=TRUE, nrow=2))
```

```r
ss <- function(x) {
    ## remove data-frame structure, convert to 2x2 matrix
    m <- matrix(unlist(x),byrow=TRUE,2)
    ## set new names
    names(m) <- c("newcol1","newcol2")
    return(m)
}
```

Apply the function to each row and `rbind()` together:

```r
rbind(ss(dd[1,]), ss(dd[2,]))
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to include something.