# convert time format column to numeric R

Tags: r

I have a column like this: (I am using `lubridate`)

The `S.D` is a difference between order and ship date. It is gotten this way:

`mutate(S.D = mdy(Ship.Date) - mdy(Order.Date))`

```
 S.D
<time>

2 days
4 days
5 days
...
```

I want to convert it to:

```
 S.D
<int>

  2
  4
  5
...
```

How do I do that?

Comment: There is some ambiguity in what you show. I'm inferring that you're using `dplyr` (or at least `tibble`), but it isn't obvious what package you're using that is providing the `<time>`-class column. Can you please make this question more self-contained? This includes listing non-base packages, as well as providing unambiguous sample data (e.g., give `data.frame(...)`, `tibble(...)`, or the output from `dput(head(x))`). Thanks!

Comment: I did edit above

Comment: I'm glad you got an answer, but for next time ... your data is still unusable. (1) `mutate` takes as its first argument a `data.frame`, which your code does not include. (2) That notwithstanding, we also will see `object 'Ship.Date' not found`. I suggest you read https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for a more detailed discussion of "reproducible" and "self-contained".

Comment: ok, thanks, next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your initial column format? Is it character, Date?
I think you can try `SD=as.integer(as.character(SD))`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your column is in a data frame named `df`, you can use the `parse_number()` function in the `readr` package:

```
library(readr)
df$S.D <- parse_number(df$S.D)
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it says: `Error in parse_vector(x, col_number(), na = na, locale = locale, trim_ws = trim_ws) : is.character(x) is not TRUE`

Comment: Would you please edit your question to include a chunk of your dataset? You can use: `dput(head(your_data_here))`